# How to add a flight booked by someone else to Google calendar that includes tracking?

Tags: google-calendar

I'd like to keep track of the flights some friends and family are making.

When I book for myself, the flight gets added to Calendar, from the booking confirmation in my mail. It is also tracked. If there are changes to the flight (e.g. cancelled, delayed), I get an update.

Is there any way to add other peoples flights to my calendar in the same way, without having the booking confirmation?

Answer (score -1):

You can manually add flights to Google through their trips website.
https://www.google.com/travel/trips

You have to create a new trip then add a flight and enter your flight details. I've been looking for this all day and I finally found it. So hopefully it helps.

Comment: I tried this and it's halfway there -- I'm confident that having it in trips generates the tracking. I just haven't seen the flight also show up in my calendar, even when creating a new trip (and sharing it with myself via the share button for good measure)